# How is interference of electrons (double slit experiment) explained in Heisenberg's Matrix Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, double-slit-experiment

How is interference of electrons (double slit experiment) explained in Heisenberg's Matrix Mechanics?

Comment: Per handwaving I would say that technically you would have to make the transition from matrices to differential operators, first... so you might as well go with the Schroedinger equation right away, because that's where you will end up one way or another.  See the part about "Further results" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics. It's an interesting question if discretized versions of interference actually converge properly.

Comment: QM diffraction is is plain Heisenberg-Jordan-Born amplitude interference, in constructing the probability of the electron at a distance *y* from a centerpoint on the screen. Thus, you only need to describe a 2D (y; and x, the propagation dimension from the slits) free Gaussian wavepacket, a standard introductory exercise. No wave razzmatazz needed, just the plain free propagator. It is basically ray optics with an interfereing phase shift. Tomonaga's ***superb*** QM text does it for you.